# restricting and redirecting based on a boolean value in an angular application

Tags: angularjs, routes

I would like to restrict and redirect access to certain routes in my angular app. I realize there were other questions similar to this, but because angular and firebase keep evolving, some of the earlier solutions no longer work and I would like to have the simplest possible solution as my current goal is not to make a production app, but an app that works.

I can log in and log out and every time I log in I set a rootscope variable to true and every time I log out I set that variable to false. Given this, how can I restrict my routes and redirect to the login page when the user isn't logged in?

```
angular
  .module('angularappApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'firebase'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/chat', {
          templateUrl: 'views/chat.html',
          controller: 'ChatCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
          templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
          controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .when('/register', {
          templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
          controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .when('/logout', {
          template: 'Loging out...',
          controller: 'LogoutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }).constant('FBURL', 'https://dazzling-inferno-7746.firebaseio.com/');
```

This is my app.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to implement such a feature in your app is watching page changes and cancel transition if condition is failed.

In your example you can watch route changes and check if `$rootScope` has specific attribute true or false.

```
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    // check if user is login if not then prevent default action
    // and redirect user to login page
    if(!$rootScope.isLogin){
      event.preventDefault();
      $location.path('login');
    }
  });
```

and I suggest that you should put this code block in a run block or at least config block as they are first things to start work in angularjs applications...

and strongly suggest you to use [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) over default routing as it has much more features then default ones...

**restrict specific page**

if you want to restrict a specific page you can add a custom attribute on its defination and check if it is pass all condition then give it a go...

```
.when('/chat', {
      templateUrl: 'views/chat.html',
      controller: 'ChatCtrl',
      // add a custom property for checking at route changes
      requireLogin: true
  })
```

then in your event block check it like that

```
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    // get next route
    var nextRoute = $route.routes[$location.path()];
    // check if next page requires login then
    // check if user is login if not then prevent default action
    // and redirect user to login page
    if(nextRoute.requireLogin && !$rootScope.isLogin){
      event.preventDefault();
      $location.path('login');
    }
  });
```

Comment: I just want to require authentication for the chat page though. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by the event block?

Comment: ah, i realized that you had to put it inside .run( function($rootScope, $location, $route) {(your code)}. now, it works. i also changed isLogin to the boolean var I had.

Comment: cool I still suggest you to change to ui.router if it wont give you a headache...

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz how to achieve this with Angular ui router?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu You can check this example https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/require-authentication-for-certain-routes-with-ui-router-in-angularjs